# How to use apostrophe in product name?

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to use apostrophe in product name while creating setup with InnoSetup.

I am defining a variable this way:

```
#define APP_NAME = "ABC's tool"
```

and I am using this variable in AppName, AppVerName and OutputBaseFilename.

If I define it as shown above, I get following error:

```
Compile Error!
Line: 185
Error: Column 50:
comma (',') expected.
```

If I change the variable definition to:

```
#define APP_NAME = "ABC''s tool"
```

it compiles OK, but I get double apostrophe in product name (ABC''s tool).

Any thaughts how to define in order to get one apostrophe?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, I should have tested this before. I am defining AppName with more variables, for example:

```
#define APP_NAME = "ABC's tool"
#define APP_VER = "2012"
[Setup]
AppName = {#APP_NAME} {#APP_VER}
```

I have tested this and it works with new file. But still, if I do it in my script,  I get an error.

I have solved it, so I hardcode the APP_NAME, wherever I want to use it, e.g.:

```
AppName = {ABC's tool} {#APP_VER}
OutputBaseFilename=ABC's tool {#APP_VER}
```

Comment: Even the `OutputBaseFilename={#APP_NAME} {#APP_VER}` works just fine. What version of InnoSetup are you using ?